# Are convex objects determined by their silhouettes?

Tags: geometry, convex-hulls, computer-vision

Informally, the silhouette of a 3D shape is a viewpoint-dependent 2D projection of it. You might imagine looking at several silhouettes and attempting to construct the overall shape.  My question is theoretical: if you have access to the set of all silhouettes of a convex figure —unordered, that is to say, you know only the silhouettes, not the viewing angles associated with each one—is that always sufficient to uniquely reconstruct the shape?

Or are there convex shapes that are not related via any rigid transformation that have indistinguishable silhouette profiles?

I have been working on this problem, and I'm stumped.  So far, I've tried generating asymmetric (chiral) shapes, and attempting to answer the question in two dimensions instead of three.

---

Here's one attempt to formalize these terms: if $P$ is a (bounded) convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, let $u\in S^2$ be a viewing direction. The *silhouette of $P$ in the $u$ direction*  is the set of all vectors $v\perp u$ such that the line through $v+u$ and parallel to $u$ intersects the object.

Two convex subsets $P, Q\in\mathbb{R}^3$ have the same *silhouette profile* if there is a rigid transformation $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that the set of all silhouettes of $f(P)$ is equal to the set of all silhouettes of $Q$.

The question is whether there are convex subsets $P,Q\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ that are not the same shape (not related by a rigid transformation), but have the same silhouette profile.

(These definitions carry over to other dimensions with $\mathbb{R}^3$ replaced with $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $S^2$ replaced with $S^{n-1}$.)

Edit: In order to entirely erase the viewing direction from the silhouette, I should quotient these silhouettes by the relation that considers silhouettes equivalent if they can be transformed into one another by a rigid transformation.

Comment: You formal definition of silhouette usually *does* encode the viewing angle, because all vectors in the silhouette lie in the orthogonal complement of $\{u\}$. So if there are 3 non-colinear points in the silhouette, we can recover $\operatorname{span}\{u\}$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Yeah, I wasn't sure exactly how to quotient those out of the definition of silhouette. But the formalization of my question asks about *silhouette profiles* instead of the silhouettes themselves, and I think this avoids that problem?

Comment: Oh --- not completely. Thanks. I'll think about how to fix it.

Comment: The supporting hyperplane theorem ensures you can always create a well-defined orthographic projection for every viewing direction. So the silhouettes shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The problem is that I originally asked about recovering the object from the silhouettes without any information on the viewing angle.  But because of the way I formalized silhouettes, they encode their viewing angles such that we can't have a situation where two nearby viewing angles yield silhouettes s1 and s2 of P,  and two very far viewing angles of Q yield those same silhouettes, and a rigid transformation maps s1 and s2 of P onto s1 and s2 of Q --- the representation of s1 and s2 preserves information about relative viewing angle that i had intended to erase.

Comment: I presume you're allowing what you're calling a "rigid transformation" to include a reflection?  Otherwise, the answer is almost trivially "no". Let $\ A\ $ be any $3$-dimensional convex body with no rotational symmetry (e.g. a tetrahedron with all edges of different lengths) and $\ B\ $ its reflection. The silhouettes of these bodies in opposite directions will be reflections of each other, so their silhouette profiles must be identical. However there can be no sequence of translations and rotations that transforms one into the other.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera rigid transformations are isometries which includes reflections.

Comment: This strongly reminds me of [a question I put a bounty on recently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4801422/what-projections-of-convex-bodies-can-tell-us-about-their-volumes). While the question was ultimately not answered properly, Marco did point to an interesting result in his partial answer. It doesn't really deal with the "unordered" nature of the projections, but you may be interested nonetheless.

Comment: Rather than performing a quotient on the set of silhouettes to get rid of the information about the viewing angle, you could fix $u$ (say $u = (0,0,1)$ and consider the silhouettes of $T(P)$ for $T$ ranging over all the kinds of transformations you are interested in.